# Is there a way to plot the solutions, feasible region and the optimal solution for Linear Programming in Julia Language?

Tags: plot, julia, linear-programming, juno-ide, julia-plots

I'm wondering if ther is a package to plot the feasible region (based on the constraints) and the optimal solution for linear programming in Julia Language using Juno. Do you know a way to do this? Suppose we have a LP problem and want to visualize the region and optimal solution. Is there a package to do this? How can I do this. I would appreciate so much your help. Thanks.

Comment: Very difficult to plots things beyond 3 dimensions. Most meaningful plots are problem-dependent.

Comment: it can just be two or three dimensions.. two dimensions is enough for me, it it a curiosity. do you know how to plot two or three dimensons regions for linear programming in Juno?